# Voice Recording on Apple Watch on watchOS 2

Tags: speech-recognition, apple-watch, watchos-2

Is there a way to auto dismiss the voice recording controller on Apple Watch watchOS 2, to make the recording behave much like siri?

I am currently using the following method according to the Apple documentation to record voice.

```
presentAudioRecordingControllerWithOutputURL:preset:maximumDuration:actionTitle:completion: of WKInterfaceController
```

And in the docs it explains that the user has to explicitly save the recording.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?